# Oauth Login error while logging in using linkedin credentials ("error":"https_required")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, omniauth-linkedin

I am using omniauth-linkedin-oauth2 (1.0.0) gem to login the users to our site using linkedin it was working fine until now not sure if its related to linkedin API changes or what

I am getting the below error

```
| (linkedin) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: 
    OAuth2::Error, https_required: The client is not authorized
    {"error":"https_required","error_description":"The client is not authorized"}
```

Here's my configs:

```
  OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

  LINKEDIN_FIELDS =  ['id', 'first-name', 'last-name', 'picture-url', 'email-address', 'positions']

  Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do

   provider :linkedin, ENV['LINKEDIN_KEY'], ENV['LINKEDIN_SECRET'], fields: LINKEDIN_FIELDS, secure_image_url: true

end

if Rails.env.development?
  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
end

OmniAuth.config.on_failure = 
 Api::V2::UsersController.action(:linkedin_failure)
```

Comment: I am also facing the same error. Worked till yesterday, but not today. Please update if you get any solution.

Comment: We're encountering the same issue, for what it's worth. We've raised a ticket with LinkedIn developer support.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, although I'm using a different JavaScript SDK, was working fine just couple hours ago, suddenly get error https_required now

Comment: Same issue here.  All our calls are https.

Comment: apps like these are working they are using different strategy https://skrapp.io

Comment: Logged the issue here with detailed images: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56660121/linkind-oauth-failed-with-https-required-error-message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It now started working again. I think linkedin fixed it from there end.