# LinkedIn OAuth failed with https_required error message

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

Our goal is to get the access token from Linked In API so that we can fetch the current user detail. We are following the API mentioned here: [OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Flow (2-Legged)](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v2/oauth2-client-credentials-flow)

The response we are getting from the API is:

```
{"error":"https_required","error_description":"The client is not authorized"}
```

Here is the request made via ARC:

[image]

Here is the setup at the LinkedIn App Management portal:

[image]

The URL from where the LinkedIn login is being called (the Client)

[image]

You can verify from the above three screenshots that for all the following cases **HTTPS** is being used:

1. LinkedIn Requested URL for the POST request.
2. Redirect URI in PayLoad.
3. Redirect URI set in App at LinkedID portal.
4. Client URL from where LinkedIn login is requested.

Can someone share why the LinkedIn OAuth is still throwing "error": "https_required"?

Answer (score 3):

I was having this exact problem, where I have an existing app, and all of a sudden today I was having this issue, when it was all configured correctly.

It now started working for me again, therefore I assume there was a temporary bug on LinkedIn's end